# Error while using TestNg DataProvider must return either Object[][] or Iterator<Object>[], not class [[Ljava.lang.Object;

Tags: java, selenium, apache-poi, testng, testng-dataprovider

**Testcase:**

```
package Test;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import Page.LoginPage;
import Utility.TestDataProvider;
import Utility.TestUtil;
//Testcase to perform login 
public class LoginTest  {
LoginPage page=new LoginPage();

@Test(dataProvider="ExcelDataProvider",dataProviderClass=TestDataProvider.class)
public void Logintest(String username,String password){

//page.login("user@phptravels.com","demouser");
page.login(username,password);
    }
@AfterTest
public void TearDown(){
    TestUtil.quit();
}
}
```

DataProvider:

```
     package Utility;
        import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
        import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
        import org.testng.annotations.Test;
        public class TestDataProvider {
        static ExcelReader reader=new ExcelReader();
        @DataProvider(name="ExcelDataProvider")
       public static Object[][] ExcelDataProvider()
         {
        Object [][] rest = reader.readDataExcel("UserLogin");
        return rest;
    }
     }
```

ExcelReader:

```
package Utility;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFTable;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


public class ExcelReader {

    static String fileName="Testdata";
    public Object[][] readDataExcel(String TableName){
        String filePath="F:\\TravelSite\\TravelSiteAutomation\\Testdata.xlsx";
        File file =new File(filePath);


        try{
        FileInputStream stream=new FileInputStream(file);
              Workbook workbook  = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);
              XSSFSheet sheet=(XSSFSheet) workbook.getSheet("UnitTest");
                 List<XSSFTable> tables = sheet.getTables();

                 for(XSSFTable table:tables){
                     String name=table.getName();
                     if(name.equals(TableName)){


                         int ci=0,cj=0;
                        int rowNum=sheet.getLastRowNum()-sheet.getFirstRowNum();
                        //System.out.println(rowNum);


                        String[][] dataArray=new String[rowNum][100];
                        for(int i = 1; i < rowNum+1; i++) {

                            Row row = sheet.getRow(i);



                            //Create a loop to print cell values in a row
                            int colNum=row.getLastCellNum();
                           // System.out.println(colNum);
                            for(int j = 0; j <colNum; j++) {


                                //Print excel data in console
                                  Cell cell=row.getCell(j);
                                  DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
                                  String var_name = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                               System.out.print(var_name+" || ");
                               dataArray[ci][cj]=var_name;

                            }

                            System.out.println();
                           }
                        workbook.close();

                return dataArray;   
                        }   

                     }
                 Log.info("Table name is incorrect");
                 return null;
                 }



            catch(Exception e)

        {
                Log.debug(e.getMessage());


                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

so when i try to run the testcase i get an error 
org.testng.TestNGException:

> Data Provider public static java.lang.Object[][]
>   Utility.TestDataProvider.ExcelDataProvider() must return either
>   Object[][] or Iterator[], not class [[Ljava.lang.Object;

Nothing seems to resolve it,POI version 3.15, TestNGversion 6.10

Comment: You sure your data provider is not returning null?

Comment: Yes.Not returning Null

Comment: It looks like a bug. Could you open a issue on https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/ ?

Comment: Ok, let me raise a bug.

Comment: @sajalsingh can you test this with providing the static data, the same excel reader class would return. Also try it with older or newer version.

Comment: I'm kind of curious why you didn't implement singleton to done this task.
Also why your code here looks different then code that you reported on github?

Comment: So was getting error due to the parsing issue, there was some mistake in the logic of the reader have corrected it.Still not sure why that was causing the TestNg failure, seems error message is wrong when the for Object tries to return null in dataprovider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `ExcelReader` class. Please find below the fixed version of the same which should solve the problem

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFTable;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ExcelReader {

    public static String[][] readDataExcel(String TableName) {
        String filePath = "src/test/resources/Testdata.xlsx";
        try {
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(filePath);
            XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) workbook.getSheet("UnitTest");
            List<XSSFTable> tables = sheet.getTables();

            for (XSSFTable table : tables) {
                String name = table.getName();
                if (! name.equals(TableName)) {
                    continue;
                }
                int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum() - sheet.getFirstRowNum();
                System.out.println(rowCount);
                int columnCount = - 1;
                List<List<String>> data = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 1; i < rowCount + 1; i++) {
                    Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
                    int colNum = row.getLastCellNum();
                    if (columnCount == - 1) {
                        columnCount = colNum;
                    }
                    List<String> rowData = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int j = 0; j < colNum; j++) {
                        Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
                        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
                        String var_name = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                        if (var_name != null && ! var_name.trim().isEmpty()) {
                            rowData.add(var_name);
                        }
                    }
                    if (! rowData.isEmpty()) {
                        data.add(rowData);
                    }
                }
                workbook.close();
                String[][] dataArray = new String[rowCount-1][columnCount];
                int rowIndex = 0;
                for (List<String> row : data) {
                    int colIndex = 0;
                    for (String rowData : row) {
                        dataArray[rowIndex][colIndex++] = rowData;
                    }
                    rowIndex++;
                }
                return dataArray;
            }
            System.err.println("Table name is incorrect");
            return new String[][] {{}};
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new String[][] {{}};
        }
    }
}
```